# Is it possible to inject different repository classes based on application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have different property files for *MySql* and *Mongo* database, which are loaded at start up based on maven profiles.

For the mongo is also needed to inject an another repositry: **MongoRepository** instead of **CrudRepository** as it is for the MySQL.

So is it possible to solve this with a property in the *application.properties*, and based on this property inject one or the other repository?

My app is a simple spring-boot app and the repository is injected from the controller.

Comment: You should provide sample codes of `MongoRepository`, `CrudRepository`, and the place where you inject them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume both repositories have a common interface where you want to load the actual bean. I'd try something like this: (I didn't test it)

```
@Autowired
MongoRepository mongoRepository;
@Autowired
CrudRepository crudRepository;

@Value("isMongo")
boolean isMongo;

private Repository actualRepository;

 @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    actualRepository = isMongo ? mongoRepository : crudRepository;
  }
```

Perhaps you can even create a bean if you need this repository in several other beans:

```
@Bean
public Repository actualRepository(@Value("isMongo") boolean isMongo, MongoRepository mongoRepository, CrudRepository crudRepository) {
  isMongo ? mongoRepository : crudRepository;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes that is very doable.  In Spring Boot you would do this via [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).  Using profiles you can enable or disable `@Repository` (and other `@Components`).

```
@Repository
@Profile("mongo")
public interface MyMongoRepo extends MongoRepository<SomeObject, String> {

}


@Repository
@Profile("mysql")
public interface MyMysqlRepo extends CrudRepository<SomeObject, String> {

}
```

Obviously you can use whichever profile name you want.  The profile can be set via command line or via the application.properties file.

```
spring.profiles.active=mysql
```